# PLSQL : Open file in write mode

Tags: file, plsql

It is probably something simple but I ask it anyway :

I want to popen a file in write mode (not appending), it starts from the beginning. If the file does not exist, it should be created it.

I tried this :

```
ficErrors := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(myDirectory, errorsFilename, 'W');
```

I have this error :

ORA-29283 invalid file operation ORA-06512 at "SYS.UTL_FILE"

ty

Answer (score 0):

Do it like:

```
Declare

  fHandle  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
begin
  fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('BDUMP', 'test_file', 'w');

  UTL_FILE.PUT_Line(fHandle, 'This is the first line');
  UTL_FILE.PUT_Line(fHandle, 'This is the second line');
  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fHandle, 'This is the third line');

  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fHandle);
END;
```

where `BDUMP` = is the directory where my file will be created. It's on the server where Oracle is installed.

See Demo:

```
SQL> Declare
        fHandle  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
      begin
          fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('BDUMP', 'test_file', 'w');

          UTL_FILE.PUT_Line(fHandle, 'This is the first line');
          UTL_FILE.PUT_Line(fHandle, 'This is the second line');
          UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fHandle, 'This is the third line');

          UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fHandle);
      END;  
  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Output:

```
unixterminal$ ls -lrt test_file
-rw-r--r--   1 oracle   dba           70 Mar 10 15:21 test_file
```

Note:

If the oracle OS user does not have the appropriate `privileges` on the OS directory, or if the path specified in the `database` does not match to an actual path, the program will hurl this exception:

```
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, I think you should check directory permission for your current user.
`GRANT READ/WRITE ON DIRECTORY myDirectory TO yourUser;`

> Update: If you have already set database permission, need to check OS permission. Please check OS permission and all parent directories as well.

Comment: It has been done before normally  but I am checking it with the Systems departement

Comment: I have the write privilege

Comment: @mlwacosmos. If you are sure you have all the privileges, then there is no reason it will not work.

Comment: I found it... I had to do a chmod in the file system

Comment: If you all erase your answers, I can delete this question