# plsql CSV file reading and write

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
OWNER   SYS
DIRECTORY_NAME  ME
DIRECTORY_PATH  \\172.16.20.11\Mad\


begin

vSFile := utl_file.fopen('ME','20170405.csv','R');
IF utl_file.is_open(vSFile) THEN
LOOP
```

i am getting error :

```
ORA-29283: invalid file operation ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536 ORA-29283: invalid file operation ORA-06512: at "MADHUR.MSP_UPD_DAILYSALESFRMSAP", line 28 ORA-06512: at line 1
29283. 00000 -  "invalid file operation"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
           not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the
           operating system.
*Action:   Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
           and if reading, verify that the file exists.
```

Comment: What's the issue? Have you done what the error message says?

Comment: Does Oracle really allow (recognise) a network path in Windows as [a directory on the server file system](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/glossary.htm#CNCPT44466)? Can you map that path to a drive letter and see if that works? (Could also be an issue with OS permissions or Oracle grants, of course...)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for getting such issue is that you dont have `read` or `write` permission to the `directory`.

Run the below query to see if you have `read` and `write` priviledges:

```
 SELECT * 
      FROM all_tab_privs 
     WHERE table_name = 'your_directory name';
```

If you find dont have any access then grant read and write privs.

```
SQL>CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY dir1 as '/opt/oracle/';

SQL>GRANT READ,WRITE on dir1 to <Required user>; (if you want to give access to particular user)
OR
SQL>GRANT READ,WRITE on dir1 to PUBLIC; (if you want to give access to all users then give access to public)
```

Comment: @kumarh. If you have the permission then under no circumstances you must get this issue. See my post here with demo : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720366/plsql-open-file-in-write-mode/42720486#42720486

Answer (score 0):

Your error tells you exactly what the problem is:

`*Cause:    An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
           not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the
           operating system.`

and what to do to fix it:

`*Action:   Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
           and if reading, verify that the file exists.`

So you specify:

`DIRECTORY_PATH  \\172.16.20.11\Mad\`

are you able to actually access `\\172.16.20.11\Mad\` with your oracle user?

if not, then you need to `grant read, write on directory to user` and also check OS permissions for your user to that path.

but also consider doing a network share to drive letter, instead of UNC path.

Comment: i am able to access this path and i have permission read and write

Comment: as which user are you able to access it?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact rules are about what Oracle can or can't open as a directory, but on Windows there is a difference between named drives and URLs even though Windows Explorer can present both the same way. For example I can `dir "\\ln-sharepoint.blahblah.net\Root\whatever\docs"` or browse it in Explorer and it'll appear as a regular folder, but if I try to `cd` to it I get `CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.`